# how to call js method that exist in 2 js files?

Tags: javascript, html

To my html file i add 2 js files

```
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js_001.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js_002.js"></script>
</head>
```

both those js files contain method call 'func1'

1. How i call func1 from js_002 ?
2. If there is method func1 => js_001
           and method func2 => js_002

When i call the func2 from my html code - i get an error about that func2 does not exist on js_001 ... why is that and how to fix it ?

Comment: You can't. The one in `js_002.js` will override the one in `js_001.js`. This is why you should not pollute the global namespace.

Comment: You don't; if they're in the global namespace it's overwritten. That's why JS has multiple "module" tricks, so you avoid stomping over existing references.

Comment: What Derek said. If you have no control over editing or combining the two js files, then I would rewrite the function in a third file, with a new name and a new life. Witness protection program.

Comment: i add something more to my question please

Comment: Your edit doesn't change Derek's point.

Comment: Are you trying to call a function in `js_002.js` from `js_001.js`? If that's the case, just switch the load order.

Comment: @Parapluie I am having flashbacks for jQuery's `.noConflict`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions defined with the same name in the `global` scope will overwite themselves. Last definition will overwite the previous one.

So you could populate your functions inside other scopes, for example, objects:

```
// In js_001.js
var js_001 = {
    foo : function() {

    }
};

// Inside js_002.js
var js_002 = {
    foo : function() {

    }
};
```

Then you can invoke both functions by: `js_001.foo();` and `js_002.foo();`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

As others said you can't. That is why for example using [modules](https://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/) is a good idea when you have larger applications.

You could write your scripts in your functions in the js files inside a module that includes all functions related to some functionality like this

**File js_001.js**

```
var js_001 = (function () {

  return {
    foo : function () {
      // code
    }
  };

})();
```

**File js_002.js**

```
var js_002 = (function () {

  return {
    foo : function () {
      // code
    }
  };

})();
```

And call your functions like this:

```
onclick="js_001.foo()"
onclick="js_002.foo()"
```